# Show container only if text inside it

Tags: css

I have a container a the top of the webpage which I use to dynamically display status messages. 
By default the container is empty but it's still visible because the of the red background and the padding.

How can I make this container visible only if there is text inside it using CSS?

```
#status_container {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  margin: 5px 8px;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
}
<div id="status_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, apply styling to a child element.  Then use CSS to display that child element if it exists like so:

```
.status_container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.status_container > p {
  padding: 6px 16px;
  margin: 5px 8px;
  background: red;
}

<div class="status_container">
    <p>Upload successful.</p>
</div>
```

Set `overflow: hidden` on parent so that the margin of the child `p` is still visible

See this [<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/LZC2S/5/) of an empty and full message.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [CSS :empty class](https://www.google.com/search?q=%3Aempty&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#q=css+%3aempty&safe=off), triggers while object is empty.

Comment: Please don't reference W3Schools. Also, `:empty` is not supported by IE < 9

Comment: It's the first hit on Google, sorry. Go for it, pick one: https://www.google.com/search?q=%3Aempty&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#q=css+:empty&safe=off !And true, not support for < IE 9. But most time I make a backup for that, if really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove the vertical padding, and play around with `line-height`. This way, without any content, the container won't have a height.

For example:

```
#status_container {
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    margin: 5px 8px;
    height: auto;
    background: red;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

See this [<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/aKhfm/1/)